# How to ignore delete in couchbase unidirectional replication?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have bucket1 at datacenter1 and i am replicating it on datacenter2 via XDCR (unidirectional)

Now i just want that if there is any update or creation of document occur on bucket1 on datacenter1 then it should get replicated on datacenter2 but if there is any delete operation on any document of bucket1 on datacenter1 it should not replicate on datacenter2 .

In simple terms , i want to ignore delete operation on documents while unidirectional replication .

How can i do that ? Is there any setting in couchbase (i am using couchbase server 3.0) or any other way possible ?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no way to do that with XDCR in Couchbase.  Is your goal to archive all data in one location but have just operational data in the other?  It may be worth filing a feature request over at https://issues.couchbase.com.

Since the source is open and what you're talking about isn't a super hard feature, you could try implementing it at the receiving side.  Most of the hard work is configuration/UI kinds of things.